# Mongoose post aggregate hook on $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework, hook, mongoose-schema

I have aggregation query of collection A with a $lookup on collection B.
I want to set post hook on collection B that add some field to the found docs.
And my question is it possible to use schema post hook to be triggerd when collection is a part of lookup?

I add

```
    B.post('aggregate' (docs, next) => {
    // do my stuff 
    Next()
    })
```

It's work for `B.aggregate()`
But not for case when B is part of $lookup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.